# Equivalent of AngularJS Component require property in Angular Component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

I am upgrading a large Angular 1.6 App and we have number of components which use 'require' to get access to parent component's controller. AngularJS component looks like:

```
 var tileTextbox = {
        template: '<ignore>',
        controller: TileTextboxController,
        bindings: {
            field: '<',
            notifyError: '&',
            context: '<',
            onRemoteFieldAction: '&',
            onChange: '&'
        },
        require: {
            formsCtrl: '^gsForm' ----> What should this be replaced with in Angular component?
        }
    };
```

I found @ViewChild which gives Parent access to Child but I am looking for other way around. I know we could refactor an use some sort of shared service but at this point I am just looking for minimal refactor. From Angular's documentation @ https://angular.io/guide/upgrade
it does look like your component can use 'require' but just don't know how

Comment: To add to above, the parent component is AngularJS, this is an Hybrid app with some components being moved to Angular

Answer (score 1):

`require` equivalent in angular is `Host`. You can use [`Host`](https://angular.io/api/core/Host) decorator to acquire the parent component instance. For the same you have to mention parent component/directive/service name inside child component consturctor.

```
constructor(@Host() private gsForm: GsForm) {
   //here you will have access to parent directive gsForm
}
```

Comment: this didn't really work, I am guessing GSForm is an old AngularJS

Comment: @pateketu are you trying to communicate between AngularJS to Angular??

Comment: Yes, its an Hybrid App, most of the components are in AngularJS and just starting to move component-by-component to Angular

Answer (score 0):

From [**AngularJS Docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):

> **Intercomponent Communication**
>
> Directives can require the controllers of other directives to enable communication between each other. This can be achieved in a component by providing an object mapping for the `require` property. The object keys specify the property names under which the required controllers (object values) will be bound to the requiring component's controller.

Essentially this is required to share data between two Components. There are multiple ways of doing that in Angular.

1. You could create a SharedService and inject it in both the Angular Components. Set data from one component and retrieve data from the other.
2. You could use `@Input` properties to pass data from Parent to Child.
3. You could use `@Output` properties to pass data from Child to Parent.

There are many other ways of sharing data between parent and child components. `ViewChild` etc for instance. But the above three are the most straight-forward ways.

Comment: using @Input()formsCtrl is plan B, I like @Pankaj-Paker 's approach